# Calling another method that specializes in download files

Tags: java, netbeans

I had been using Netbeans since I started programming and every time I wanted something done (downloading CSV from online, scan a file and paste it into another file, etc.), I just create a JButton and put and make it an action event, it is very easy with NetBeans GUI since i can just right click on the button and click Action Performed, and all the codes will be written for me.

That worked very well until a week ago, when one method can contain up to 10,000 lines of codes (I am not joking).  So that's 1 month of work down the drain and I decided to start from scratch.  Regardless, the 1 month helped since it was my first program and I did not even understand what a "method" or "class" is.  (Irrelevant but funny, my previous code contains 18,000 lines and it is all written on one page because I have no idea how to call another method from another class).

Now I know that if I wanted to call a method from another class, I can just write: `test.calculation()` to access the method calculation() from test's class.

But now I ran into another problem, it seems like the purpose of calling another method is to get the return value of that method.  I am currently working on writing a method which will run different things depending on the integer, and I have a feeling that it will goes up to 100+.  The if statement would look like this:

```
 if(ID == 1){do task number 1;}
    if(ID == 2){do task number 2;}
....
    if(ID == 100){do task 100;}
```

I am on task number 1, which involves downloading files from websites and editing them, the code for task number 1 is around 120 lines.

I am planning on making a new Java Class which does specifically that task, so instead of having 120 lines of code I can just have one code, something like this:

```
if(ID == 1){call class/method to do task};
```

But I am running into a few problems that I believe does not solve the root cause, some errors include non static cannot be referenced in static etc...

All I wanted task number 1 to do is to download a file and edit it.  Anything is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you´re struggeling to solve `non static variable cannot be referenced in a static context` i´d rather start with basic java instead of trying to create a file download.

Comment: @KevinEsche I know how to download files and such.  What I am struggling with is calling a method that has the codes to download the file.  Whenever I put     public void abc()    I cannot call it, I have to make it     public static void abc()     in order to call it.  Is there a work around?  I am willing to let go of the whole "method" concept and try something new provided that it is what professional programmers use to do it.